# How does mongo retain order of an object when defining an index?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, indexing

From the mongodb docs

[image: The order of the fields listed in a compound index is important. The index will contain references to documents sorted first by the values of the item field and, within each value of the item field, sorted by values of the stock field. See Sort Order for more information.]

[Docs link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/)

But in javascript you can't depend on the order of keys in an object . So how does mongo reliably preserve the order of `item` and `stock` in the above example of a compound index?

Comment: I would consider it a really bad way of doing things, but in JavaScript since a few years ago the order of insertion of new properties is specified to be maintained. Thus, when you construct a new object like in your example, "item" will be the first property. Of course, if the object comes from some other code, even though the property names are the same that assumption may not hold.

Comment: It would be much more robust (in my opinion) if the API required an array of objects.

Comment: Where is it specified that key order will be retained?

Comment: It's been in the spec since I think ES6 (2015). Prior to that, *most* JavaScript environments worked that way already. I still think it's an extremely fragile way of doing things.

Comment: The problem (to me) is that you can have two objects that *look* the same, but based on their life histories, one may have "items" as the first property, while the other doesn't.

Comment: Yeah I would agree... As nice as the syntax is, it struck me as weird to depend on the order of object keys. I guess I learnt that order is actually preserved as per the spec just like es6 Map. Are there any edge cases or gotchas versus using `Map`, in terms of ordering?

Comment: Yes, keys that are numeric (well, strings that "look like" numbers) always come before (or after; I think it's before) other keys, if you use `Object.keys()` or `for ... in`. I personally cannot imagine relying on that for a software system; it seems philosophically invalid, regardless of the spec.

Comment: @david_adler I am not sure what is the exact question but i predict two questions: 1) It will store index settings in a collection, and same order of object properties as we were given while creating 2) You can read about index building process in this [index-creation doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-creation/).

Comment: @turivishal you've totally misunderstood the question unfortunately. Thanks for trying though!

Comment: @david_adler The order of the keys in your code, be it JS, Java, Python etc., is completely irrelevant here. The order that the docs mention refers to the fields that are covered by the index, i.e. the internal optimised structure to improve lookup times. So if the index is created as {item, stock} then that's what the index will be sorting by. First by item then by stock. In MongoDB, or WiredTiger to be more precise, these are generally implemented as B+ Trees. Geo and Search stuff have different structures in use. If I get some time later I'll post a detailed answer to this. Not a promise :)

Comment: The index document passed to the `db,collection.createIndex` is _not_ JavaScript object - its a MongoDB document. It is like JSON, but not a JSON either.

Comment: I think you're right that it might not be the nodejs drive @prasad_ but looking at the nodejs driver the documentation is the same and it accepts an object for a compound index so the problem remains valid https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/indexes.html#index-field

Comment: @iska but the order of the keys in my code determines the order that compound index prefix ordering is created. I know what a B+ Tree is, AFICS the ordering of the keys in my code determine the order of the B+ Tree key.

Comment: The documentation to the latest NodeJS driver API - for [createIndex](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.1/classes/Collection.html#createIndex)

Comment: Thanks much better link! But yeah it kind of proves my point right @prasad_ the compound index ordering depends on the JS object key order...

Answer (score 1):

No idea what the folks at MongoDB were smoking when they defined this API. As you have rightly pointed out, the JavaScript object only represents the unordered collection of key-value pairs both by design and spirit. For ordered collection, one could use array of objects.

The recent versions of JavaScript specifications encourage preserving the creation order of keys in the object for Object.keys and such methods. As others pointed out in the comments, relying on creation order of properties for the Object parameter for an API is plain stupid. It becomes even muddier if the object is cloned, the cloning library maintains the order or not. But probably it works since recent implementations now a days honors creation order and they pass the constant object inline.